# Android JSON Exception when parsing

Tags: java, php, android, json

I have this PHP script that I am using it for a json array in android application, but I am getting this message

> Android Value … of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

each time I run the android application

**PHP** script:

```
<?php
function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jerusalem');
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);

    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

    $string = array(
        'y' => 'سنة',
        'm' => 'شهر',
        'w' => 'أسبوع',
        'd' => 'يوم',
        'h' => 'ساعة',
        'i' => 'دقيقة',
        's' => 'ثانية',
    );

    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
        if ($diff->$k) {
            $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? '' : '');
        } else {
            unset($string[$k]);
        }
    }

    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . '' : 'الآن';
}

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$db = "finaldatabase";

if (isset($_GET["userName"]) && !empty($_GET["userName"])) {  

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db);

if(!$conn)
{die ( "Connection failed");}

$query = "select *
          from teamnews,teaminterest
          where teaminterest.userName = '".$_GET['userName']."' 
            and teamnews.TeamName = teaminterest.teamName"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$rows = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $News_Titles[]=$row['teamnews_title'];
      $Images[]=$row['teamnews_image'];
      $News_Text[]=$row['teamnews_text'];
      $Time_Stamp[]=$row['teamnews_timeStamp'];
      $News_Url[]=$row['teamnews_newsURL'];
}

sleep(2);

$offset = isset($_GET['offset']) && $_GET['offset'] != '' ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;


$limit = 20;
$movies_array = array();

for ($j = $offset; $j < $offset + $limit && $j < sizeof($Images); $j++) {
    $tmp = array();
    //$tmp['rank'] = $j + 1;
    $tmp['newstitle'] = $News_Titles[$j];
    $tmp['image']=$Images[$j];
    $tmp['newstext']=$News_Text[$j];
    $tmp['time_stamp']=  'منذ'.time_elapsed_string($Time_Stamp[$j]);
    $tmp['news_url']=$News_Url[$j];


    array_push($movies_array, $tmp);
}

echo json_encode($movies_array,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);



}

exit();
?>
```

and this s my **json** code in the android

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(LoadNewsUrl+"?userName="+restoredText, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    if (response.length() > 0) {
                        array.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Item item = new Item();
                                    item.setNews_title(object.getString("newstitle"));
                                    item.setNews_text(object.getString("newstext"));
                                    item.setNews_image(object.getString("image"));
                                    item.setNewss_TimeStamp(object.getString("time_stamp"));
                                    item.setNews_URL(object.getString("news_url"));

                                    array.add(item);

                            } catch (JSONException ex) {

                               Log.e("Exception ", ex.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                        newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }


                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    Log.e("Error Response",error.getMessage());

                }


            }


            );
```

And this is my json format:

```
  [{"newstitle":"Barca Test 1 ","image":"http:\/\/alinstagram.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/12\/%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1-%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%8A-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%B4%D9%84%D9%88%D9%86%D8%A9.jpg","newstext":"Dummy Text","time_stamp":"Ù…Ù†Ø°1 ÙŠÙˆÙ…","news_url":"http:\/\/alinstagram.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/12\/%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1-%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%8A-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%B4%D9%84%D9%88%D9%86%D8%A9.jpg"},{"newstitle":"Barca Test 2","image":"http:\/\/alinstagram.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/12\/%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1-%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%8A-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%B4%D9%84%D9%88%D9%86%D8%A9.jpg","newstext":"Dummy Text","time_stamp":"Ù…Ù†Ø°1 ÙŠÙˆÙ…","news_url":"http:\/\/alinstagram.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2014\/12\/%D8%B5%D9%88%D8%B1-%D9%86%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%8A-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%B4%D9%84%D9%88%D9%86%D8%A9.jpg"}]
```

if anyone can help me with that ?

Comment: From what you have above it looks correct. Are you sure that's the full json format? The error is saying that your response is not a json array...

Comment: yes sir it's a full json format but i don't know why it's giving me this problem